# Using CSS, surely there is a better way to write this Flex code?

Tags: html, css

I needed some help with Flex. I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L65oI.jpg) using flex but I cant seem to align all the items to the left for both. The code I provided below works just fine, but I'm sure there has to be a better way to do it but nothing seems to be working for me.

Here is a [CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/emonhoque/pen/ZEewWra) for anyone who would like to help me.

```
<div class="sidebar">
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
    <div class="sidebar-nav-line">
        <div class="sidebar-nav-text">
            <p>Home</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-icon">
            <img class="sidebar-nav-icon-img" src="assets/img/sidebar-icons/home.png" alt="Home-Icon">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-nav-line">
        <div class="sidebar-nav-text">
            <p>About Me</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-icon">
            <img class="sidebar-nav-icon-img" src="assets/img/sidebar-icons/about_me.png" alt="About-Me-Icon">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-nav-line">
        <div class="sidebar-nav-text">
            <p>Projects</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-icon">
            <img class="sidebar-nav-icon-img" src="assets/img/sidebar-icons/projects.png" alt="Projects-Icon">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-nav-line">
        <div class="sidebar-nav-text">
            <p>Resume</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-icon">
            <img class="sidebar-nav-icon-img" src="assets/img/sidebar-icons/resume.png" alt="Resume-Icon">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-nav-line">
        <div class="sidebar-nav-text">
            <p>Contact</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-nav-icon">
            <img class="sidebar-nav-icon-img" src="assets/img/sidebar-icons/contact.png" alt="Contact-Icon">
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    width: 255px;
    height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-nav-line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.sidebar-nav-text{
    margin-right: 15px;
    align-self: center;
    color: #dec29b98;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav-icon {
    margin-right: 32px;
    align-self: center;
}

.sidebar-nav-icon-img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The description is confusing because it states "_but I cant seem to align all the items to the left for both._" then goes on to state: "_The code I provided below works just fine_..." Does this work to the best of your knowledge?

Comment: It does work, I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do it. For now, i have stuck to using padding or margins to achieve what i am trying.

Comment: Use Flex and flex-direction just like div, I will post the example using Flex and direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a little with css and ended up with this. I don't know if it's really what you wanted, but maybe it can help you get some new ideas.

```css
*{margin: 0;font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;}
html{background-color:#1c1c20;}
.col{
  display:grid;
  width:200px;
  background-color:#2c2c2c;
  height:100vh;
}
.menu{
  width:95%;
  padding-top:10%;
}
.box{
  text-align:right;
  color:#dec29b98;
  padding:5px;
}
.box > div{
margin-right:10px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="menu">
      
      <div class="box">
        <div>LINK 1</div>
        <div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png"></div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
        <div>LINK 2</div>
        <div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="box">
          <div>LINK 3</div>
          <div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png"></div>
      </div>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried it out and it works for me too! I just wanted to know if there's a better way to achieve it and this certainly seems better. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @EmonHoque Remember to not only check answers, but also upvote answers you find useful. It gives the answerer a confidence boost seeing those imaginary numbers tick up ^^